# Adding a finalizer to a JavaScript Promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, finalizer

I'm looking for a way to add a [finalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) to a JavaScript Promise chain. In the following code experiment I attempt to use [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) for this purpose but it is not suitable since it executes immediately instead of waiting for the other steps to finish first. I'm looking for a solution that would let me delay cleanup steps until the Promise is no longer needed.

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .finally(() => console.log('cleanup'))
  .then(() => console.log('initialize'))
  .then(() => console.log('do things'))
```

Comment: You can use `Async/await` for this and put cleanup code always at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed some detail, but if the intention is that `finally` is executed after the other promises then move it to the end of the stack:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('initialize'))
  .then(() => console.log('do things'))
  .finally(() => console.log('cleanup'))
```

Comment: My intention was to define cleanup step before I pass the handle forward to some mystery code since I can not force the mystery code to pass the promise back to me once they are done with their mystery operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `Promise.all()` in this case like so.

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'done')).then((x) => {console.log('a'); return x;}).then((y) => {console.log('b'); return y;}).then((z) => {console.log('c'); return z;});

Promise.all([myPromise]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of your `then()` return a Promise

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    let promise = Promise.resolve()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('initialize')
            return Promise.resolve('foo')
        })
        .then((data) => { // data = 'foo'
            console.log('do things')
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log('after 2 seconds, cleanup')
        })

    promise.then(() => console.log('do more things'))

})();
```